# Trapezoid area in terms of side lengths

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

I went ahead and supposed $AB = 3, DC = 2$ since it is a ratio, we can change it later in the end.

Area $= \frac{1}{2}(5)(h)$ the height is the difficult part, I cannot use $a, b$ anywhere here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Triangle $AMD$ has area $\frac{ab}{2}$, so triangle $ABD$ has area $ab$. It follows that triangle $DBC$ has area $\frac{2}{3}ab$, and now we are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $H$ the midpoint of $AB$. Note that the height of the trapezoid ( say $\overline{DK}$) is $\overline{DK}=\frac{ab}{\overline{AH}}$. So we have:
$$
Area=\frac{\left(2\overline{AH}+\frac{4}{3}\overline{AH} \right)\cdot \frac{ab}{\overline{AH}}}{2}
$$

Comment: How did you get the height of the trapezoid?

Comment: The height of the trapezoid is also the height of the triangle $ADH$ with respect to the side $AH$. And, for the same triangle, the height with respect $AD$ is $b$, so $ab=\overline{AH}\cdot \overline{DK}$.